# Как правильно удалять фрагменты?

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager

У меня есть главное `Activity`, на котором расположен `ViewPager` и `NavigationTabBar` с `Fragment` 1-3. Из этих фрагментов можно запускать еще фрагменты (1.1-2.1), которые полностью закрывают предыдущие фрагменты, но не закрывают `NavigationTabBar`. Во фрагментах 1.1-2.2 есть кнопка назад, а также их можно закрыть нажатием аппаратной кнопки назад. Подобное реализовано в приложении Yandex Market.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как эти фрагменты правильно закрывать. Просто удалить последний фрагмент из стэка (`popBackStack`) не выход, так как пользователь может сначала открыть Fragment1.1 во Fragment1, затем пролистнуть до Fragment2 там открыть Fragment2.1, снова пролистнуть до Fragment1 и нажать кнопку назад на самом фрагменте 1.1. Сейчас пользователь видит Fragment1.1 и по идее он и должен закрыться, но если писать так:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

то исчезнет последний фрагмент, а мне нужно определенный.
Если писать так, то фрагмент исчезнет, но из стэка не удалится:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.remove(DonatFragment.this).commit();
        }
    });
```

Пытался удалить по имени или id, не сработало:

```
DonatFragment hidenFrag = (DonatFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

fragmentManager.popBackStack(hidenFrag.getId(), 0);
fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentTag, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Этот код удаляет тот фрагмент, в котором находишься:
`getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTrasaction().remove(this).commit`